# For any integer $n > 0$, when exactly is $x_1 \oplus x_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus x_n$, satisfied? Find a pattern, then use induction to prove

Tags: logic

For any integer $n > 0$, when exactly is $x_1 \oplus x_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus x_n$, satisfied?
Find a pattern, then use induction to prove

---

The pattern I found is its true if odd number of $1's$

$P(n): $ for string of n variable $x_1 \oplus x_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus x_n$ is true if and only if it has odd $\#$ of $1's$
Attempt of proving withing induction

Base Case:

let $n = 1$

$1 \oplus 0$ holds and $0 \oplus 1$ holds (this is n = 2 nvm)

EDIT: Single variable and has to have odd number of $1's$ so it's 1 only meaning it holds

Inductive step: Let $n > 1$. Suppose $P(n)$ holds whenever $1 \leq j < n$

WTP: $P(n)$

Two cases $x_1 = 0$ and $x_1 = 1$

could someone tell if the pattern is correct and how to go about this? Thank you.

case 1: $x_1 = 0 \to $ odd $1's$ from $x_2$ to $x_n$

$0 \oplus 1$ by IH it'll total to $1$, so holds

case 2: $x_1 = 1 \to $ even $1's$ from $x_2$ to $x_n$

$1 \oplus 0$ since there are only 0's, this holds

Comment: Your base case doesn’t match it’s proof (you’re the proving $n=2 case here). The proof so far seems fine, although you may need a slightly stronger $P(n)$ (try turning it into an if-and-only-if).

Comment: Took your advice and attempted the inductive step

Comment: I recommend starting base cases at $0$ (strengthening the theorem a bit in this case). This is often simpler and the exercise of figuring out what the theorem means for $n=0$ is often enlightening.

Comment: The question states $n > 0$

Comment: @TreeGaren Yes, hence my parenthetical comment about strengthening the theorem. If you've proven the theorem for $n\geq 0$, you've proven it for $n>0$ too.